# Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name. - Moodle mobile app - Ionic - FCM

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, moodle

I am trying to add Notification feature in Moodle Mobile App using Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I am getting an error while building the Ionic app.

> cordova build android
> Conflict found, edit-config changes from config.xml will overwrite plugin.xml changes
> Removing permission "android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" from AndroidManifest.xml
> cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 122 source files in 3077ms
> [cordova-plugin-push::before-compile] skipping before_compile hookscript.
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/egp/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=/home/egp/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
> Using Android SDK: /home/egp/Android/Sdk
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 41s
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
> Subproject Path: app
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>
> Configure project :app
> Adding classpath: com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10
> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
> WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
> Build file '/home/egp/moodleapp_with_notification_github/moodleapp/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 352
>
> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'.
> Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
> Command failed with exit code 1: /home/egp/moodleapp_with_notification_github/moodleapp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/egp/moodleapp_with_notification_github/moodleapp/platforms/android/build.gradle
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>
> cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
>
> Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the notifications module you are loading adds googleServices but your app already has this added.

Find the line that goes like:

```
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

And comment it out by adding `//` in front. Then rebuild the project, the error should go away!

Alternatively, disable the platform from adding the GoogleServicePlugin by changing this value in `config.xml` to false.

```
<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" />
```

This will prevent the build process from adding the google service plugin which you plugin already adds.

Comment: After commenting that line in platforms/android/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated/XXXXXXX_FCMPlugin.gradle, I get this error: 
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mohsin,
Changing this value to false in config.xml solved the problem:

```
<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="false" />
```